# Spring boot allows user logg in more than one times concurrently (Solved) but it cannot redirect to specific web page (still not working)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, spring-security

Hi I am trying to limit user concurrent logins to 1 (this has been solved). However always the system redirects to login?error page when the user is trying to login for seccond time concurently. As you can see in my code I have tryied the following three options but still it doesnt redirect to any of them

- .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login?othersession=true")
- .invalidSessionUrl("/login?session2=true")
- .expiredUrl("/login?othersession3=true")

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.21.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.24.RELEASE and the code is the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/logout";
public static final int SESSION_TIMEOUT_SEC = ((int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(60));

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiHttpSecurityConfig.class);

private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final UserService userService;

public MultiHttpSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                               PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                               UserService userService)
{
    this.userDetailsService = new UserLoginHandler.UserDetailsServiceWrapper(userDetailsService);
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ApiSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**") //<= Security only available for /api/**
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/public").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/lost").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login?othersession")
        ;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/VAADIN/**", "/ui/HEARTBEAT/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/privacy**", "/terms**", "/favicon.ico**")
            .permitAll();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/ui/PUSH/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();


        http
            .addFilterAfter(new UserLoginHandler.InetAddressFailureFilter(), RequestCacheAwareFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error3")
                .successHandler(
                new UserLoginHandler.LoginSuccessHandler(MultiHttpSecurityConfig.this, "/", true))
            .failureHandler(
                new UserLoginHandler.LoginFailureHandler("/login?error"))

            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logged-out")

            .permitAll()
          /*      .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login?othersession")
                .sessionFixation()
                .newSession()*/
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login?othersession=true")
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login?session2=true").sessionFixation()
                .newSession()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/login?othersession3=true")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())        ;
        http.csrf().disable() // We'll use Vaadin's CSRF protection
            .headers()
            .cacheControl().disable() // disable spring security cache headers
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin(); // SAMEORIGIN policy is required for downloads to work
    }

    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public  ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on what I have wrong or what can I do in order to redirect to logint?othersession ?
PS. I do not use xml file for listener definition

Comment: Your  `MultiHttpSecurityConfig` should be an `@Configuration` as well. One `@EnableWebSecurity` is enough and you only enabled concurrent session management for the `/api` URL not the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it works for me. 

I added the sessionmanagement() under the next configure(HttpSecurity http) method for login and now it works ok. However if the user is trying to login with seccond session the url is still the /login?error even I have defined   .expiredUrl("/login?othersession"). 

Do you know how I can define the url that comes after a failed login due to concurent session?

Comment: Expired is something different then concurrent login. Expiry will happen after the user logs on, and the session has timed-out and the user tries to do access the site.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum. I understand that expiry is for this. Then how can we forward the user in a specific error page after concurrent login?Does anyone can help me on this?

Comment: That is the `session-authentication-error-url` as explained [in the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-concurrent-sessions).

Comment: Thank you once again M. Deinum

Comment: I did the following but unfortunatelly it doesnt work. this is what I have done: 

                .and() 
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login?othersession=true")
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/login?othersession2=true")
                    .sessionFixation()
                    .newSession()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .expiredUrl("/login?othersession3=true")
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comments, instead put them in your question.

Comment: You have right. I have updated the code and the question. I think now its more easy to read someone the (partially) working code.

Comment: Does anyone has any advise on how to redirect users that trying to login concurently or to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This should work, if it doesn't there is something you aren't explaining in the question.